# How can I post a JSON string to the server via jQuery $.ajax()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON object that I've "stringified" in JavaScript that I'd like to post to the server.

I'm testing this with simple PHP script that just prints the `$_POST` array.  Unfortunately it's always empty.  What am I missing?

myJsonFile.json

```
{"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":{"title":"S","GlossList":{"GlossEntry":{"ID":"SGML","SortAs":"SGML","GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym":"SGML","Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef":{"para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso":["GML","XML"]},"GlossSee":"markup"}}}}}
```

post-json.js

```
$.get('myJsonFile.json',function(myJsonString) {
    // other stuff happens here, I promise :)
    console.log(myJsonString); // looks like a nicely formed json object to me
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'view-json.php',
        data: {json: JSON.stringify(myJsonString)},
        success: function(data) {
            // success message
        },
        dataType: 'json',                // These are the offending lines. Remove.
        contentType: 'application/json'  // Thanks A.Wolff!
    });
},'json');
```

view-json.php // always empty array

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: How do you check `$_POST` is empty?

Comment: Good question, I'm using Google Chrome developer tools, checking the Network tab, clicking on the post-json.php entry and looking at the response.  In the Headers I can see the Request Payload shows the json object is sent: `json=%7B%221%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22...`, but the Response is always: `Array()`. Also, my success message shows, um, successfully.

Comment: At least try removing `dataType: 'json'` (you aren't returning json here so internal parsing will throw an error) and inside success callback use `console.log(data);`

Comment: Try removing `contentType` too

Comment: Thanks. `dataType` removed and `console.log(data)` added.  Console.log(data) returns `Array()` as well.

Comment: Removed `contentType` and it printed just fine! Thanks! Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it right away.  Also, can you share why this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `contentType` specify the type of data you send to server. You set it as json but you are not sending javascript object using JSON notation, so server reject request (i'm not sure how each server handles it). Same can be said for `dataType`, while your server wasn't returning JSON.